# Candy on Let's Go Pikachu/Eevee

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

I played through *Let's Go Eevee* and am now playing *Let's Go Pikachu*, and when I catch pokémon they don't give any candy, even at a catch combo of 100, just berries. I've only beaten 2 gyms so far, so perhaps they start giving you candy later on in the game.

Is my game messed up? When does catching pokémon grant you any kind of candy?

Answer (score 2):

The Pokemon Candy obtained via catching are indeed locked at the beginning. You need to **catch 120 Pokemon** before you'll obtain those sweet Pokemon candy. [Source](https://www.serebii.net/letsgopikachueevee/catchrewards.shtml)